# Creating a Pagination object with Can.js

Tags: javascript, canjs

I'm creating a pagination observable object. I instantiate it with a collection, and it has a derived `paginatedList`, and sometime later I update it's master list (say I've filtered the data). Obviously I want the derived list to recognize that and re-render the view, but it doesn't. Something must not be bound right.
[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/v9zejkrr/)

```
var Pagination = can.Map.extend({

    pageNumber: 1,

    pageSize: 10,

    isFirstPage: can.compute(function() {
        return this.attr('pageNumber') === 1;
    }),

    isLastPage: can.compute(function() {
        return this.attr('pageNumber') === this.attr('lastPage');
    }),

    lastPage: can.compute(function() {
        return Math.ceil(this.attr('list').attr('length') / this.attr('pageSize'));
    }),

    paginatedList: can.compute(function() {
        var pgn = this.attr('pageNumber'),
            pgs = this.attr('pageSize'),
            start = (pgn-1) * pgs,
            end = start + pgs;
        return this.attr('list').slice(start, end);
    }),

    prevPage: function() {
        if (!this.attr('isFirstPage'))
            this.attr('pageNumber', this.pageNumber-1);
    },

    nextPage: function() {
        if (!this.attr('isLastPage'))
            this.attr('pageNumber', this.pageNumber+1);
    },

    toPage: function(pageNumber) {
        this.attr('pageNumber', pageNumber);
    }
});

var paginated = new Pagination({ list: collection });
```

...and the template would look something like...

```
<table>
    {{#paginated.paginatedList}}
        <tr>
            ....
        </tr>
    {{/paginated.paginatedList}}
</table>
```

Then, sometime later, the user filters the list...

```
paginated.attr('list').replace(collection.filter(function() {
    // return filtered collection
}))
```

But the view does not re-render. What isn't bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, an attempt to explain what I believe is happening in your example:

Understanding how the can.compute is figuring out how to publish/emit it has changed is maybe not obvious, but in your example the compute `paginatedList`, will emit the fact that it has changed when any of the properties `pageNumber`, `pageSize`, or `list` change, you can see this within the compute by which properties are accessed using the `.attr()` accessor method.

The `replace` method in a can.List replaces the items **within a list** not the list itself, so in
this example, the property accessed by `.attr('list')` does not actually change (nor does 
`pageNumber` or `pageSize`), it is still the same instance of a list it just has different items 
in it now, so the computed value does not update, which in turn does not update the template.

As a simple/naive fix to the example you could just replace:

```
paginated.attr('list').replace(collection.filter(function() {
    return Math.random() < 0.5;
}));
```

with

```
paginated.attr('list', collection.filter(function() {
    return Math.random() < 0.5;
}));
```

...ie, replacing the whole list, not just the items within the list.

Here's a fiddle with that change http://jsfiddle.net/phx1jgq1/1/

Of course this might not be what you are looking for, maybe you actually want to bind to a list where the items may change.
The problem here is that `this.attr('list').slice(start, end);` doesn't really bind to all the individual items of the list, but something like:

```
this.attr('list').filter(function(item, index){
    return index >= start && index < end;
});
```

...does, so you could just replace that line to have it work like you expect.

Here's a fiddle with that change: http://jsfiddle.net/n2tygdud/1/

Of course if filtering through all the items doesn't feel right, you probably want to look into the **[define plugin](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.prototype.define.html)** that let's you map out advanced and specific behaviours to can.Maps like getters, setters and type conversion, and use that to bind to a lists add/remove events and update a computed property accordingly.